# Disable $http default headers for certain hosts

Tags: angularjs

I'm setting a couple of default headers using `$http.defaults.headers.common` for communication with our API – e.g. the *Authorization* header. This saves me a lot of trouble of specifying these headers on every individual `$http` request or `$resource` declaration.

However, in one place I'm making an `$http.get` call to the Foursquare API and the fact that the additional headers exist is a problem a) obviously I don't want to send the authorization header to anything other than our API and b) the existence of the headers forces `$http` to use CORS and Foursquare rejects the OPTIONS request.

Is there any way I can set the defaults on a per-host basis or using some other context? I've tried moving the directive that contacts Foursquare into its own module hoping the defaults might be isolated that way but they're not.

I guess I can `delete` the additional headers from `$http.defaults` prior to the Foursquare request and restore them afterwards but it feels like a horrible hack and might be problematic if any requests to our API are attempted while waiting for the Foursquare response to come back.

Comment: Also worth noting that I found that while I can explicitly turn off the headers by passing `{headers:{Authorization:null}}` to the `$http.get` the request still gets pre-flighted so that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good way to solve this without having to use `$http.defaults`.

Instead I register an interceptor as described in the [Angular docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http#description_interceptors). Within that I can modify the request config as I please:

```
request: (config) ->
  if config.url.indexOf('http://myhost.com') is 0
    if $cookies.AuthToken? and not config.headers['Authorization']?
      config.headers['Authorization'] = "Token #{$cookies.AuthToken}" 
  config
```

```

Answer (score 1):

What you may consider doing is creating a service as an abstraction layer. In that service you can compare the url with a list of trusted endpoints (your api) and only add the header if the url matches.

```
(function () {
'use strict';

var serviceId = 'webRequest';
angular.module('app').factory(serviceId, ['common', 'config', '$http', '$cookies', webRequest]);

function webRequest(common, config, $http, $cookies) {
    var $q = common.$q;

    var service = {
        WebRequest: WebRequest
    };
    return service;

    function WebRequest(method, url, data, okCallback, koCallback) {
        //inspect url here and if it matches config.trustedEndpoint or something similar          then...
        var promise = $http({
            method: method,
            url: url,
            data: data,
            headers: { 'Authorization': $cookies.AuthCookie}
        }).success(okCallback).error(koCallback);
        //otherwise, make the call without the header.
        return promise;
    }
}
})();
```

Additional approach would be to extend ng-Resource and override the default implementation for get.

Another approach may be to extend ng-Resource and override the default implementations.

```
var module = angular.module('customResource', ['ngResource']);

module.factory( 'Resource', [ '$resource', function( $resource ) {
    return function( url, params, methods ) {
      var defaults = {
      get: { method: 'get' }
      };

    methods = angular.extend( defaults, methods );

    var resource = $resource( url, params, methods );

    resource.prototype.$get = function() {
        //inspect url of this here and add header if needed

    };

    return resource;
};
}]);
```

Comment: I think that would be a great idea if I wasn't using `$resource` almost everywhere so the actual `$http` call is a layer of abstraction below what I'm dealing with. In the case of the Foursquare request I'm using `$http` directly but it's with the `$resource` usage that using `$http.defaults.headers` really shines.

Comment: Another approach in this scenario may be to extend ng-Resource and override the default implementations. I can provide a sample if you'd like.

Comment: I added an example for extending ng-Resource to the answer.